# Unity - Hacer RELOJ de tiempo invertido en mi juego 00:00:00

Tags: c#, unity

Hola estoy haciendo un juego en el que necesito contar las horas, minutos y segundos para saber que tiempo ha invertido el jugador en la partida. Pero solo consigo la hora actual:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using TMPro;

public class TiempoTranscurrido : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text textClock;

    void Start()
    {
        textClock = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        DateTime time = 00:00:00;
        string hour = LeadingZero(time.Hour);
        string minute = LeadingZero(time.Minute);
        string second = LeadingZero(time.Second);
        textClock.text = "Time: " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
    }

    string LeadingZero(int n)
    {
        return n.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0');
    }
}
```

Comment: Necesitas almacenar esa información en algún lado. Guardar hora de inicio, hora de finalización, y al costado tener la diferencia. Al final, hacer una sumatoria de todos esos registros.

Comment: Hola Andrés podrías decir si la respuesta te resultó útil y en caso de haberlo sido marcarla como aceptada y dar tu voto, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer uso de la **clase Stopwatch**, siguiendo lo que ya tienes hecho te recomiendo lo siguiente:

```
public class TiempoTranscurrido : MonoBehaviour
{
   public TMP_Text textClock;
   Stopwatch cronometro = new Stopwatch();

   void Start()
   {
      textClock = GetComponent<TMP_Text>();
      cronometro.Start();
   }

   void Update()
   {
      TimeSpan ts = cronometro.Elapsed;
      string tiempoTranscurrido = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
                 
      textClock.Text = tiempoTranscurrido;
   }
}
```

La **clase Stopwatch** funciona como un cronómetro, lo que hacemos aquí es empezar el cronómetro en tu **método Start** y en tu **método Update** vamos actualizando el tiempo transcurrido.

La instrucción:

```
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Nos guarda el tiempo transcurrido desde que empezó a correr el cronómetro, este tiempo transcurrido es el que mostramos en pantalla.

Para detener el cronómetro puedes usar la siguiente instrucción:

```
cronometro.Stop();
```

Esta instrucción quizá debas ponerla cuando finalice la partida, para que el cronómetro no siga corriendo(este análisis te toca a ti).

Para poder usar la **clase Stopwatch** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```